# Why does pandas.read_csv read all of the blank values in one code but not the other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing code that requires use of the pandas.read_csv function and I like to use a test python file before I implement my code into the main python file. The part of the CSV file I am trying to read in just has data displayed in a seemingly random fashion with no real columns or headers. I just want to read the information into a dataframe so I can parse the data exactly where I know it is going to be for every file. For the test code and the main code I am using the same list of CSV files. The only difference is the test code runs in a different folder and does not sit inside a function. In my test code I have no issue extracting data from the CSV file using the read_csv function but on my main program it is giving me errors. In my test code I can easily use pd.read_csv this way:

```
for x in range(len(filelist)):    
   df = pd.read_csv(filelist[x], index_col=False, nrows=15, header=None, usecols=(0,1,2,3), 
        dtype={0:"string",1:"string",2:"string",3:"string"})
   print(df)
```

The output is shown below:

[Output from test code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD40L.png)

However, when I try to port this over into my main code it won't function the same way. If I copy the code exactly it says there is no column 1,2, or 3. My next step was to erase the usecols and dtype variables and then it gave me the error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 2

I tried adding the comma delimiter and I tried changing the engine to python. Neither worked. Eventually, I determined from the tokenizing error that the program was expecting less information on certain lines so I broke up the code so that there were two dataframes and each would hold a respective amount of columns. This finally worked. The dataframes I created were structured as shown below:

```
    df1 = pd.read_csv(filelist[x],skiprows=range(1), index_col=False, nrows=11, header=None)   
    df2 = pd.read_csv(filelist[x],skiprows=range(0,13), index_col=False, nrows=2, 
        usecols=(0,1,2), header=None)
    print(df1)
    print(df2)
```

The output for this is shown below:

[Output from main code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCN1b.png)

This gives me something I can work with to accomplish my task, but it was extremely frustrating working through this and I have no idea why I even needed to go through all of this. I still will have to go back through and make some final adjustments including all the calls to the variables I need from these so if I can figure out why it is not working the same in the main code it would make my life a little easier. Does anyone have any clue why I had to make these adjustments? It seems the code for my main program is not reading in empty cells or just takes the amount of spaces used for the first row it looks at and just assumes the rest should be the same. Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I am adding the full error messages below. I made it so it only calls the first file in the list for debugging purposes. This first one is when I copy the read_csv command over exactly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jacob.hollidge\Desktop\DCPR Threshold\DCPRthresholdV2.0.py", line 484, in <module>
    checkfilevariables(filelist)
  File "c:\Users\jacob.hollidge\Desktop\DCPR Threshold\DCPRthresholdV2.0.py", line 221, in checkfilevariables
    df = pd.read_csv(filelist[0], index_col=False, nrows=15, header=None, usecols=(0,1,2,3),
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 933, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1231, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._validate_usecols_names(
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py", line 913, in _validate_usecols_names    
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: [1, 2, 3]
```

This next error occurs after I remove usecols and dtype from the parameters.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jacob.hollidge\Desktop\DCPR Threshold\DCPRthresholdV2.0.py", line 483, in <module>
    checkfilevariables(filelist)
  File "c:\Users\jacob.hollidge\Desktop\DCPR Threshold\DCPRthresholdV2.0.py", line 221, in checkfilevariables
    df = pd.read_csv(filelist[0], index_col=False, nrows=15, header=None)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1250, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 225, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 817, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 2
```

This final set of errors is given after I add the delimiter=',' and engine='python' parameters while usecols and dtypes have still been removed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jacob.hollidge\Desktop\DCPR Threshold\DCPRthresholdV2.0.py", line 483, in <module>
    checkfilevariables(filelist)
  File "c:\Users\jacob.hollidge\Desktop\DCPR Threshold\DCPRthresholdV2.0.py", line 221, in checkfilevariables
    df = pd.read_csv(filelist[0], index_col=False, nrows=15, header=None, delimiter=',', engine='python')
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1250, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 270, in read
    alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 1013, in _rows_to_cols
    self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num + 1)
  File "C:\Users\jacob.hollidge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 739, in _alert_malformed
    raise ParserError(msg)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 13, saw 4
```

Comment: At first glance, what's the purpose of using a for loop to assign a single dataframe `df` ?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: what do you have in file? Your all problem is in file - it is not correct. There is difference between `empty column` and `non-existing column`.

Comment: @abokey I have a list of csv's I am iterating through.

Comment: @furas I went ahead and added the full error messages as you suggested, also you can see what is in the file if you look at the output generated by the test code. I am applying the code to the same file. That is why this is so confusing and frustrating.

Comment: The problem is, those are NOT CSV files.  They are just textual data files.  A CSV file has the same number of fields in every line.  Convenience methods like `read_csv` are handy when your data fits their rigid rules, but yours does not.  You may need to read the file by hand, and extract the data into a list of lists, and then import that into a DataFrame.

Comment: *"when I try to port this over into my main code it won't function the same way"* <-- your code doesn't run a different way when it's in a loop. instead, you're just encountering issues in the full set of files which you didn't in your sample file. print out the file paths as you read them in, figure out which one is causing the issue, and then update your code to handle *all* of your files, not just the first one. there's no silver bullet to dealing with messy data that we can help you with. if your files have different formats, that's a bummer, and you need to write code that handles it.

Comment: so - sorry, but "the function I wrote to read in one file doesn't work when I read in a different file" isn't an issue with pandas or a programming issue we can help you with. you just need to figure out what the format(s) of your data is(are) and write code that handles it. data cleaning sucks :/. If you have a specific question about handling a specific error, chances are it's been asked here before, but if it hasn't feel free to post a question about just that. But we can't answer the question "how do I read in all of my different files?"

Comment: @TimRoberts then why would it work in one program but not the other? It as if it looks through the whole file in my test code then determines there are blank lines where data is missing in columns, but in my main code it looks at the first line then determines every line should look the same after that.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I am using the same loop and the same data in both files. Sorry when I re-read my initial statement I see why it could be confusing. When I say test file I mean a test python file not test csv file. The execution of read_csv seems to be getting treated differently from one to the other for some reason. It is as if the way pandas is looking through the files is different. Refer to my response above to TimRoberts.

Comment: One example is using `skiprows`, and one is not.  Right?  That results in very different behavior.

Comment: @TimRoberts I only added that because it wouldn't work without that in my main code. That is where I mention having to break the data apart into two different dataframes. At first I had copy and pasted the code exactly so it should have behaved the same. That is the entire point of my post. Somehow it is not acting the same when I use the command with the same exact parameters.